# Behaviour of PHP API change when sending json data

Tags: php, angularjs, api

I've a php script who manage the connection of a user. When the connection is accepted by the script, a JSON web token is sent to the web service. The problem is, when I test my connection API with this web service, the script send me nothing without error. However, when i test it with postman, the script send me that token.

Here is my PHP script :

```
//Now create the TOKEN
$jwt = JWT::encode(
    $data,
    $secret_key,
    $algorithme
);

$unencoded_array = ['jwt' => $jwt, 'admin' => $admin];
//echo "test";
echo json_encode($unencoded_array);
```

And here is my client call :

```
$rootScope.Connect = () => { 
  //Set params to request
  var request = Global.url_api+'action=Connection&username='+$scope.username+
  '&password='+$scope.pwd+
  '&project='+$rootScope.project;

  //Ask to the server if credentials is correct
  $http.get(request)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
}
```

BUT, when i uncomment this

> echo "test";

I receive my token with that string as you can see here :

[image]

Any idea ? if you need more information, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: It's unusual to send credentials via a `GET` request. Are you sending it as a `POST` in Postman, perhaps?

Comment: I send it as a `GET` via postman too